# Set sort order for mongoose document

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a mongoose schema:

**models/profile.js**

```
var mongoose = require("mongoose");
var passportLocalMongoose = require("passport-local-mongoose");

var profileSchema = new mongoose.Schema({ 
    username: String,
    complete: { type: Boolean, default: false },
    email: { type: String, default: "" },
    city: { type: String, default: "" }
}, { discriminatorKey: 'accountType' });

profileSchema.plugin(passportLocalMongoose);
module.exports = mongoose.model('Profile', profileSchema);
```

That has two discriminators associated with it:

**models/finder.js**

```
var Profile = require('./profile');

var Finder = Profile.discriminator('finder', new mongoose.Schema({
    position: { type: String, default: "" },
    skills: Array
}));

module.exports = mongoose.model("Finder");
```

**models/helper.js**

```
var Profile = require('./profile');

var Helper = Profile.discriminator('helper', new mongoose.Schema({
    jobTitle: { type: String, default: "" },
    lastPosition: { type: String, default: "" }
}));

module.exports = mongoose.model("Helper");
```

I am using this within an express framework, and on one page - shown below - I want to iterate over the key/value pairs in `Profile` to build a table.

**I would like to retain the order designated in the Schema, so that the table ordering is consistent between pages.**

Is it possible to define a sort order on Schema creation?

Here's my `profile.ejs` file where I make the table:

```
<table class="table profile-display">
    <tbody>

    <% for(var key in profile.toObject({versionKey: false})) { %>
        <% if (key != '_id') { %>
            <% if (profile[key].length === 0){ %>
                <tr class="incomplete-warning table-rows">
            <% } else { %>
                <tr class="table-rows">
            <% } %>
                    <td class="key-text"><%=key.toUpperCase()%>:</td>
                    <td><%=profile[key]%></td>
                </tr>    
       <% } %>
    <% } %>

    </tbody>
</table>
```

Please let me know if I can provide more information

Comment: So your `for-in` loop looks fine. You're just asking if it's possible to get the keys of an object in a specific order? Like the order in which you define them in the Schema?

Comment: @BlunderingPhilosopher - exactly. I know that I could define an array with the desired sort order, and then iterate over that, but I am looking for a way to use the order I have already defined when setting up the schema

Answer (score 2):

You can use [retainKeyOrder](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/4.x/docs/guide.html#retainKeyOrder)

By default, mongoose reverses key order in documents as a performance optimization. For example, `new Model({ first: 1, second: 2 });` would actually be stored in MongoDB as `{ second: 2, first: 1 }`. This behavior is considered deprecated because it has numerous unintended side effects, including making it difficult to manipulate documents whose _id field is an object.

Mongoose >= 4.6.4 has a `retainKeyOrder` option for schemas that ensures that mongoose will always keep the correct order for your object keys.

```
var testSchema = new Schema({ first: Number, second: Number }, { retainKeyOrder: true });
var Test = mongoose.model('Test', testSchema);
Test.create({ first: 1, second: 2 }); // Will be stored in mongodb as `{ first: 1, second: 2 }`
```

References:

https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/issues/1514
https://mongoosejs.com/docs/4.x/docs/guide.html#retainKeyOrder

Comment: This doesn't work for me. See the updated question for more details. I am using mongoose `v5.4.13`

Comment: Mongoose has removed `retainKeyOrder`. From the [documentation](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/migrating_to_5.html): _The retainKeyOrder option was removed, mongoose will now always retain the same key position when cloning objects. If you have queries or indexes that rely on reverse key order, you will have to change them._

Answer (score 1):

Every browser handles object sorts differently. I suggest returning a JSON object which maps your schema that has a sort value or such and iterates over your `profile.ejs` template. Then you can just map the value from mongoose output key whichever you like.

```
{
   1 : 'username',
   2 : 'type',
   3 : 'complete',
   4 : 'email',
   5 : 'city',
   6 : 'position',
   7 : 'skills'
}
```

or an array

```
[
    'username',
    'type',
    'complete',
    'email',
    'city',
    'position',
    'skills'
]
```

Then from that, you can just map your schema from the value of the object or from the array. I like using an array in this case as its easier to iterate over by just using the index key. It depends on your usage and purpose.

Hope it help.

**UPDATE:** To minimizing in hardcoding the schema twice you can create an object which has sorts with the schema value.

Code Example.

```
// Construct your object
var objSchema = {
    obj1 : {
        schema : { type: String },
        order : 2
    },
    obj2 : {
        schema : { type: String },
        order : 3
    },
    obj3 : {
        schema : { type: String },
        order : 1
    }
}

// Function to construct your schema object and sort array
function mapSortSchema(objs) {
    var result = {
        schema : {},
        order : []
    }

    for (var obj in objs) {
        result.schema[obj] = objs[obj].schema;
        result.order.push({
            'key': obj,
            'order': objs[obj].order
        });
    }

    result.order.sort(function(a, b) {
        return a.order - b.order;
    });

    return result;
}
```

Now you have schema for mongoose and order for template.

```
var mapSchema = mapSortSchema(objSchema);

// You can now use this with your mongoose schema
var forMongooseSchema = mapSchema.schema; 
// result {obj1 : { type: String }, obj2 : { type: String }, obj3 : { type: String }}

// You can now use this to loop through your template
var forTemplateLoop = mapSchema.order;
// result [{key: "obj3", order: 1}, {key: "obj1", order: 2}, {key: "obj2", order: 3}]
```

Haven't tested this in mongoose but it will give you the basic idea, you can improve the function base on your need. Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks. I would prefer to do this without specifying an array, because that requires that I hard code the order twice

Comment: I updated my answer to minimize in hardcoding the object twice